# Inline assembly 4x slower than `std::ops::Add<i8>`

Tags: performance, rust

I have a crate which wraps numeric primitives (https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/ux2).

I am testing the performance versus the raw `core::primitive` types, here (https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/ux2/tree/testing):

```rust
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};

use criterion::BenchmarkId;
use rand::Rng;
pub fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("add");
    
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    // Reduce warmup and measurement time so the benchmarks don't take as long.
    group.warm_up_time(std::time::Duration::from_millis(500));
    group.measurement_time(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));

    group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("core", 8), &(), |b,_| {
        let lhs = rng.gen_range(0..i8::MAX/4);
        let rhs = rng.gen_range(0..i8::MAX/4);
        b.iter(|| lhs+rhs)
    });

    group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("ux2", 8), &(), |b,_| {
        let lhs = ux2::i7::try_from(rng.gen_range(0..i8::MAX/4)).unwrap();
        let rhs = ux2::i7::try_from(rng.gen_range(0..i8::MAX/4)).unwrap();
        b.iter(|| lhs+rhs)
    });

}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

I'm getting

```
jonathan@jonathan-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/ux2/ux2$ cargo bench
   Compiling ux2 v0.7.0 (/home/jonathan/Projects/ux2/ux2)
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.83s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (/home/jonathan/Projects/ux2/target/release/deps/ux2-6bc559fda932b8ac)

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

     Running benches/benchmark.rs (/home/jonathan/Projects/ux2/target/release/deps/benchmark-d9482b576c6cf74e)
Gnuplot not found, using plotters backend
add/core/8              time:   [217.64 ps 221.12 ps 226.10 ps]
                        change: [-1.5311% -0.5221% +0.7828%] (p = 0.39 > 0.05)
                        No change in performance detected.
Found 23 outliers among 100 measurements (23.00%)
  1 (1.00%) low severe
  6 (6.00%) low mild
  5 (5.00%) high mild
  11 (11.00%) high severe
add/ux2/8               time:   [1.1005 ns 1.1020 ns 1.1037 ns]
                        change: [+0.9806% +1.2151% +1.4177%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Change within noise threshold.

jonathan@jonathan-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/ux2/ux2$
```

the underyling `std::ops::Add` implementation for `ux2::i7` uses inline assembly (this is generated by proc macro so this is the code that is generated):

```rust
impl std::ops::Add<ux2::i8> for ux2::i7 {
    type Output = ux2::i8;
    fn add(self, rhs: ux2::i7) -> Self::Output {
        let mut x = ux2::i8::from(self).0;
        let y = ux2::i8::from(rhs).0;
        unsafe {
            std::arch::asm! {
                "add {0}, {1}",
                inout(reg_byte) x,
                in(reg_byte) y,
            }
        }
        ux2::i8(x)
    }
}
// ...
pub struct i8(i8);
pub struct i7(i8);
impl From<i7> for i8 {
    fn from(x: i7) -> i8 {
        i8(i7.0)
    }
}
```

I see the same lackluster performance when using `u8::unchecked_add` or just `x += y;` and a variety of compilation options.

It seems the time is dominated by something other than the addition.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Probably LLVM is better at optimizing code than you…

Comment: Without assembly, the compiler may be smart enough to realize that your code does nothing and remove everything. Inline assembly blocks this kind of optimization, so the assembly really does the work. Use [`blackbox`](https://docs.rs/criterion/latest/criterion/fn.black_box.html) to make the compiler believe that you're using the result and that the inputs change: `b.iter(|| blackbox (blackbox (lhs) + blackbox (rhs))`

Comment: You're not setting all possible `options` for inline assembly: `pure`, `nomem`, `no_stack`.

Comment: May I ask why are you using inline assembly for something as simple as addition? You will never be faster than the compiler, and you will likely be slower.

Comment: @Jmb This should not have effect, since the compiler probably cannot optimize the random number generation and `iter()` is already using `black_box()` on the result.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you're right for the result, but if the compiler inlines `iter`, it may lift the addition out of the loop since `lhs` and `rhs` don't change, so you still need to `blackbox` at least one of them.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `unchecked_add` is nightly only.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light Using hand-written asm will not give you the advantages of `unchecked_add()`, it will be like regular wrapping add but worse.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, after adding all possible inline assembly options (`options(pure, nomem, nostack)`), the versions are equivalent. However, beware that this may not always be the case: for example, LLVM may use `lea` instead of `add`. In general, for something as simple as addition, never use inline assembly - the compiler will never be slower and sometimes will be faster, not to mention all other disadvantages of inline assembly such as portability.